# In ruby regex, can I match any character except an string?

Tags: regex, ruby

In ruby, I need the equivalent of:

`[^abc]     Any single character except: a, b, or c`

but for the whole `abc`, so it would read `Any single character except: abc

I've tried things like `[^(abc)]` but can't figure the right syntax

https://rubular.com/r/W6PiK89i2U1U1c

Comment: See the linked post, scroll to "*a sequence of characters*". In short: there is no way  to that in Ruby, but there are always workarounds that depend on what you need  to do.

Comment: thanks! I can't find it before..